# React JS component should return another components without wrapper

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which should return html elements and another components without wrapper.

```
var Group = React.createClass({
render: function() {
return (<tr><td>blablabla</td></tr>{this.props.arrayOfComponents});
}
});
```

How can I do this?

After ReactJS render I should receive next:

```
<table>
<tr><td>blablabla</td></tr>
<tr><td>component1</td></tr>
<tr><td>component2</td></tr>
...
<tr><td>component100</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can't. https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/maximum-number-of-jsx-root-nodes.html

Comment: Thanks, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

in React, the render method must return only one valid React component. You cannot return multiple things at once.